# Spring 3.0 SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler code execution using the Oracle Access Manager authentication

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on

I am trying to execute the onAuthenticationSuccess() method of SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler class after the successful authentication from Oracle Access Manager(SSO), but the method is not being executed. The same executes when i use the DB authentication using the spring security "/j_spring_security_check". Does any one has the idea if the SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler works with the OAM as the authentication has already been done on OAM and we are not using the "/j_spring_security_check". My scenario is i need to execute a piece of code after login, just for one time, not with the every request else i would have used a filter for the same.

here are the related security.xml entries:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the spring security configuration xml.

Comment: <sec:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="*AuthenticationSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="*AuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
<sec:authentication-manager alias="adminAuthenticationManager">
</sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
<bean id="*AuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="*.*.*.*.*.*AuthenticationSuccessHandler">
<property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/secure/home" />
<property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="false" />
</bean>
</beans> Here is the piece of code. Cant add more as have words limit

Comment: Do you have configuration of PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter?
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6295

Comment: @Michael: yes, i got the same and that is being executed. Its the post authentication code i.e. successhandler, which is not executing.

Comment: @nish: Edit your question don't post code in comments.